# Passing cookie from Java EE Web Application to connect to another application

Tags: jakarta-ee, post, cookies

There is a Java EE Web application. In the application, once a user logs on, they can click on a link that will open another browser window that will forward them a second application.

However, I need to be able to set a cookie from the first application, Java EE Web application, into the browser that gets opened for the second application. 
That is because the second application relies on that cookie to validate the identity of the user for the second application: For authentication, if you will. The second application inspects that cookie to validate the authenticity of the user, and opens the second application.

I was curious to know how I would go about implementing this solution. Are there any Java libraries that would allow me to do this? If so, which are the recommended ones? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're looking for is a Single Sign-on solution, check [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/JOSSO+-+Java+Open+Single+Sign-On+Project+Home)

You may also find [this other related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173704/which-sso-framework-to-use) useful.

[This presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/craigsdickson/fast-and-free-sso-a-survey-of-open-source-solutions-to-single-sign-on) should be a good start to decide on which solution to pick.

Comment: Actually, I just needed a way to post a cookie to the second application. Any advice on that?

Comment: Well, if your 2 applications are under the same Domain name and only have different paths like: google.com/app1 and google.com/app2 . Than you should be able create a cookie with Domain and Path specific configuration and this would cause the browser  to send the cookie to both. But this only would work if they are both under the same domain, it's a security restriction.
That said, I still believe that what you want and need is a single sign-on between 2 applications. It's safer and standard solution for your problem.

Comment: This actually is a SSO implementation; I have been able to get this to work by sending the parameters needed by the second application in a URI. However, I prefer to do this over a POST request from application one. I think I will try this with an HTTPClient, and see if that works. But: Please let me know if you have other suggestions.